# How to set up Deep Links with phonegap.build for iOS?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

Im trying to get Deep Links to work in my iOS, phonegap build app that loads a webpage from my server.

I have included the “cordova-universal-links-plugin” plugin and in my config I have this.

```
<plugin name="cordova-universal-links-plugin" source="npm" />
<universal-links>
    <host name="manmade.se" scheme="manmade" event="ul_myExampleEvent" />
</universal-links>
```

I have created a apple-app-site-association file and uploaded it to my server in the root. And it it downloads the file when I go there with the browser.

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "7MP323UK6C.se.manmade.mobilrex",
            "paths": [ "*" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

And I have set `“Associated Domains”` in my AppId before I downloaded the provision.profile

And in my index.html file I have this eventlistner.

```
universalLinks.subscribe('ul_myExampleEvent', function (eventData) {
                // do some work
                // in eventData you'll see url и and parsed url with schema, host, path and arguments
                console.log('Did launch application from the link: ' + JSON.stringify(eventData));
                alert('Did launch application from the link 1: ' + JSON.stringify(eventData));
            });
```

And as far as I understand this is all I have to do to make Deep links to work, så when I click on a https://manmade.se link in my iPhone it should open it in my app!??

So has anybody done this before? I don´t know what Im missing.
I get no error anywhere, but it is not firing the “ul_myExampleEvent” or anything else.

So any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you using anything different now that the plugin is deprecated? https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin/issues/160

Answer (score 0):

You've checked the `Associate Domain`, but you didn't add your domain there.

Add your domain with the `applinks:` prefix which is in your case `applinks:manmade.se`

Comment: Raoul, thanks, but I don´t understand what you mean? Im adding my domain in the details of applinks myappid.se.manmade.appname. Or how do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean when I create my appid? I can't set anything there as far as I can see?

Comment: please check the "Configuring the App" section from https://www.raywenderlich.com/128948/universal-links-make-connection

Comment: Thanks, but when you create a new appid at apple, you can register any app links:se.manmade.appname? You can only select the Associated Domains, nothing else?

Comment: yes, but it won't work unless you set the correct `apple-app-site-association` file in the server. Say `xyzbrand.com` app id wants to register your site as a Associate domain, but in the `apple-app-site-association` file there is no declaration of `xyzbrand.com` which will not trigger other 3rd party apps from your website.

Comment: This is my association file: https://manmade.se/apple-app-site-association and when I go there it downloads it, I guess thats what it suppose to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169828/discussion-between-ratul-sharker-and-claes-gustavsson).